# NGINX Proxy to Cloudant

Tags: nginx, cloudant

I'd like to expose some of Cloudant's couchdb features through NGINX running on my domain by using proxy_pass.  So far I have worked out a few kinks (noted below), but I am stuck as far as authorization.  Does anyone have any tips?

```
location /couchdb {
    rewrite /couchdb/(.*) /$1 break;   #chop off start of this url

    proxy_redirect off
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_set_header Host myusername.cloudant.com;   
    # cannot use $host! must specify my vhost on cloudant

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic base64-encode(username:password)";

    proxy_pass http://myusername.cloudant.com$request_uri;
    # must use a variable in this url so that the domain is looked up late. 
    # otherwise nginx will fail to start about half the time because of resolver issues
    # (unknown why though)
}
```

Using this setup, I can successfully proxy to Cloudant, but I always receive a forbidden response.  For instance, this request:

```
http://mydomain/couchdb/my-cloudant-db
```

returns

```
{"error":"forbidden", "reason":"_reader access is required for this request"}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried base64 encoding username:password yourself, rather than using base64-encode?

Comment: I'll admit I'm not much of an nginx wizard, but have you consulted [authentication with nginx as a Reverse Proxy](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Nginx_As_a_Reverse_Proxy#Authentication_with_reverse_proxy)?

Comment: @garbados yes, in my test nginx.conf, I have my username:password base64 encoded.  And I did start with the settings from the page you mentioned... I tweaked them a little bit but can't get past the forbidden json error.  I thought it might have something to do with how Cloudant handles my request.  But I'm not sure, maybe I'm just missing some other header?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the issue.  The innocuous looking rewrite rule as the first line rewrites the $request_uri and changes the $uri variable as part of request fulfillment.  $request_uri is not changed by rewrite.  So when I included that variable in the proxy_pass location, I was not properly including the edited url with the /couchdb/ removed.

Changing the proxy_pass line to:

```
proxy_pass http://myusername.cloudant.com$uri;
```

Now works without issue.  This was not an SSL problem nor a problem with Basic Authentication nor other http header issue nor a problem with Cloudant.  This was all related to the URI I was forwarding my request to.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with an error 'no resolver defined to resolve'.
I managed to solve it by actually adding a resolver. e.g.: resolver 8.8.8.8;

Ref: http://www.nginx-discovery.com/2011/05/day-51-proxypass-and-resolver.html